# Executable doesn't run from terminal

Tags: user-interface, executable, pyinstaller

I have created a simple program (executable) with pyinstaller 3.2. 
When I double-click it from nautilus, it runs perfectly, 
but when I try to run it from terminal from another folder (`/path/executable`), the ui doesn't come up. If I run it from the same path (`./executable`), it will run perfectly again.

Any idea why does it happen?

Comment: Do you by any chance get and use the current folder in your script?

Comment: I get as input a sqlite database from the script's path.

Comment: You can try to print the path (before db input) to check it is actually correct, when you get the problem. I suspect that this is the culprit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!